# JPA eclipselink disable auto commit

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

How to set autocommit false in JPA 2.0 and eclipselink 2.3.1 environment.
Currently i am fetching a jdbc connection from eclipselink session and then setting auto commit false in jdbc connection.Is there other way around to set autocommit false in jpa.

```
JpaEntityManager jpaEntityManager = JpaHelper.getEntityManager(em);
    AbstractSession session = (AbstractSession) jpaEntityManager.getActiveSession();
    UnitOfWork unitOfWork = (UnitOfWork) jpaEntityManager.getActiveSession();
    final Accessor accessor;
    if (session.isInTransaction() || session.isExclusiveIsolatedClientSession()) {
      accessor = session.getAccessor();
    } else {
      unitOfWork.beginEarlyTransaction();
      accessor = session.getAccessor();
      accessor.incrementCallCount(unitOfWork.getParent());
      accessor.decrementCallCount();
    }
    java.sql.Connection connection = accessor.getConnection();
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: Why do you need to touch the autocommit on the connection?

Comment: You can't. The principle of JPA is to be able to change DBMS anytime with no code modification, and autocommit is specific to some DBMS only.

The right thing  to do is to do it in your database for all transactions.

Comment: autocommit is a function of the JDBC driver, so the code above is fine if you switch databases.  It just shouldn't be needed - JPA should disable autocommit for transactions so that all statements can be rolled back as one.  The code seems pulled from here https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager but is using the JPA 1.0 solution though the question states you are using JPA 2.0 where you can simply unwrap the connection

Comment: i am using global temporary table in oracle 11g db. The problem is that if i don't disable autocommit each time i try to operate on that table after inserting records even though within a same transaction the table gets committed and flushing all the records.i even tried keeping them in a single eclipselink session, but no luck.

Comment: I recently found that eclispelink disables autocommit at the *explicit* beginning of a transaction and enables it after a commit. This is very surprising if you come from an oracle development background, because usually you don't have to even think about it - you expect the implicit beginning of a transaction as soon as the first DML happens directly from the client or indirectly from PL/SQL.